# Is it possible to suppress oscillation at reactive load (non inverting amp)

Tags: piezo, transducer, non-inverting

I am using a non inverting amp with B class voltage follower to drive a piezoelectric transducer (used as sonar for fish scanning in boats). I am using trains of 20 sinewave pulses (85KHz), like the ones you can see in the blue image (input).

[image]

However, at the output I am getting the green signal, which have undesired residual oscillations with the same frequency. The problem with this, is that the receiver circuit amplify the full incoming wave with a large gain - and there is no way to difference the 20 pulses from the "blank" space. This jamming effect is screwing up the data transmission.

The circuit I build in PCB is this:

[image]

I have discovered in simulation that if I decrease the value of the decoupling capacitor, in theory the oscillation tale dissapears. I will try this in the real circuit, but I would like to know which is the correct way to deal with this.

BTW, these parasitic oscillation just happens when the transducer is plugged in the circuit. I am pretty sure isnt related to the operational amplifier.

Comment: you need to dampen.

Comment: Hi. Is there a specific topic I could start researching? Damped systems, 2nd order systems and related stuff are actually a LARGE topic.

Comment: what's the purpose of `C1`

Comment: sorry, I meant C1

Comment: c1 is for decoupling purpose, to filter out any CD offset. I want a pure sinewave in the output

Comment: but C3 is already doing that.

Comment: It's true. I didnt pay attention to this detail while translating the design into Eagle. I took it out in simulation and is not making difference.

Answer (score 1):

your output stage has 1.2V  of dead-band so when the signal stops it's not driving the output to fixed voltage and so the transducer model continues to ring.

change the output stage to be class AB instead.

or replace C1 with a wire and take the feedback (R4) from Q1 base instead of from U1 output

Comment: I previously had an AB stage, using polarization with 2 diodes. I burnt around 4 transistor trying to set it up and finally gave up.

Comment: @RamiroVargas Your two bases are tied together. So there are times when both BJTs can be OFF and their emitters (sorry) just float, leaving everything on the output side left to its own oscillations.

Comment: to keep class B change the feedback as my edit suggests.

Comment: @jonk I get it...

Comment: @RamiroVargas I had imagined that folks first determined the resonant frequency of their tranducer and ***smacked*** it with a large voltage (perhaps for several cycles worth) to get it ringing. Are you trying to drive a transducer at something other than its resonant frequency? Of course, I've never done anything like this. So that's just my imagination.

Comment: @jonk. Right now I just need the resonant frequency of 85KHz. But I also want to control how many cycles exactly. I don't want to get it ringing, because I dont know how long is going to stay ringing.

Comment: @Jansen, if I place a wire instead of C1, then the output of U1 will become the same as Q1 base.

Comment: @RamiroVargas Understood. So your output needs to remain active and effectively and rapidly absorb return energy when you want to stop the transducer. Class-AB or class-A, I suppose. Class A if you can afford the dissipation.

Comment: I used to do sonar transducers for a living. The usual thing is to drive them with a square wave into a matching network. At best the things have an octave or so of useful transmit bandwidth even with a fifth order match. On the receive side,  we usually just placed a couple of anti parallel diodes in the ground lead and hooked the preamp to that point. Some series resistance in the matching network will help lower the Q, but even in water a Q below about 2 is hard to obtain so you will get some ringing. You are going to want a LOT move voltage then 12V to get useful radiated power.

Comment: Plot twist: the ringing is related to internal model of transducer. The amplifier of course needs improving. But with or without amplifier, oscillation stays the same.

Comment: @Dan Mills. Do you recommend a book, lecture or specific paper to go deeper on this topic? I am new to the project and I have been researching transducer for sonars but the information I find at google doesn't have many examples. I am using a commercial transducer I took from an old device.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix: remove C1 and C3 and use direct connection; put one of the caps in series with R2. Now add a 220 ohm resistor from the base to the emitter of the transistors. Opamp will drive the transducer directly at crossover and zero out.